# SQLite Cursor return NULL if no record found in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have problem today about retrieving data from SQLite. Here is my coding

```
public Cursor fetchDictionary(String searchword) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_WORD, KEY_DEF}, KEY_WORD + "='" + searchword + "'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Above coding if no record found, Android prompt dialogbox and force to close. Is there any way to return "no record found" error message if no record found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a try catch, and replace the `e.printStackTrace()` with your messages.

Comment: Yap, that's what I'm currently doing. No way to do then?

Answer (score 4):

You can also do the following to check if there is data at the current column index `cursor.isNull(columnIndex);`

Answer (score 1):

You have 'throws SQLException' in your code... catch the exception and determine if the exception is due to no-record-found.

Comment: "public Cursor fetchDictionary(String searchword) throws SQLException" I've put this one already.

Comment: That's saying that a SQLException can come out of this method. Add a try/catch block, so that you actually catch the exception. Right now Android is catching the exception and doesn't know how to handle it, so it just shoves up a message. Your code can catch it and handle it more intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
 Cursor mCursor =
    mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_WORD, KEY_DEF}, KEY_WORD + "='" + searchword + "'", null,
            null, null, null, null);
if (mCursor != null && mCursor.getCount()>0) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
     // rest goes here
}else{
     Toast.makeText(context,"No records found ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     // show error msg here 
}
}catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please also provide an explanation why this code is working for future readers